# Binary to Decimal Conversion App

Tags: javascript

I have created a binary to decimal calculator that needs to follow this spec:

- Arrays may not be used contain the binary digits entered by the user
- Determining the decimal equivalent of a particular binary digit in the sequence must be calculated using a single mathematical function, for example the natural logarithm. It's up to you to figure out which function to use.
- User can enter up to 8 binary digits in one input field
- User must be notified if anything other than a 0 or 1 was entered
- User views the results in a single output field containing the decimal (base 10) equivalent of the binary number that was entered
- User can enter a variable number of binary digits

My code is:

```js
binaryForm = document.getElementById('formComplete');
numberInput = document.getElementById('numberInput');
numberInputButton = document.getElementById('updateNumberBtn');
binaryInput = document.getElementById('binaryInput');
decimalValue = document.getElementById('decimalOutput');

numberInputButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var numberInputValue = numberInput.value;
    binaryInput.setAttribute('maxLength', numberInputValue);
});

binaryInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode !== 48 && e.keyCode !== 49 && e.keyCode !== 13 && e.keyCode !== 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Only 0 and 1 is allowed');
    }

});

binaryForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (binaryInput.value == 0) {
        alert('Empty');
    } else {
        var userInput = binaryInput.value;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
            var binaryDigit = parseInt(userInput[i]);
            var calcInput = (total * 2) + binaryDigit;
            total = calcInput;
        }
        decimalValue.innerHTML = total;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #2e2e2e;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Heebo, sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
    font-weight: 900;
}

input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
}

.form-body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#numberInput,
#binaryInput {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Heebo, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#updateNumberBtn,
#convertBtn {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid rgba(0,128,0,0.75);
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,128,0,0.75);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#updateNumberBtn:hover,
#convertBtn:hover {
    background: rgba(0,128,0,0.25);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-body">
  <h1>Binary to Decimal Calculator</h1>
  <label for="numberInput">Set max number of bits (Max 12 - Default 8)</label>
  <input id="numberInput" type="number" value="8" min="1" max="12">
  <input id="updateNumberBtn" type="button" value="Set Number of Bits">
  <form action="" id="formComplete">
      <label for="binaryInput">Enter a binary value</label>
      <input id="binaryInput" type="text" size="12" maxlength="8">
      <input id="convertBtn" type="submit" value="Convert to Decimal">
  </form>
  <h2>Decimal Value: <span id="decimalOutput"></span></h2>
</div>
```

Are there areas that I could improve performance-wise or by making the app easier to operate, such as the part where I am targeting the keys that the user can input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You should use the directive [`"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) that will place the JavaScript context into strict mode. This will throw errors for some common bad practices.
- Always declare variables as [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). If you are in strict mode you will get an error if you don't.
- Don't use alerts or prompts as there is no way to know if they are actually displayed (clients can turn them off) and they are very annoying.
- The key event properties [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [`KeyboardEvent.charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) have been depreciated and you should not use them. Use [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) or [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead
- Rather than filter the input via the keybpoard events, listen to the input's `keyup` and `change` events, removing bad characters automatically. Use a CSS rule to unhide a warning and a JavaScript [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to hide it again

  Filtering keyboard events means you need to check many keys that are valid (left, right, backspace, delete, etc...) which is just unneeded complexity.
- Don't wait for the user to click "Convert to Decimal", display the output automatically. This makes it a lot friendlier to use.
- JavaScript can convert binary strings to decimal for you using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). The second argument is the radix (AKA base) of the number that is being parsed.
- If you are just setting text (no HTML) use the elements [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) rather than [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

### Rewrite

The rewrite is following the points you have set-out in your question. I have not implemented how your code differs from these points.

The rewrite uses

- a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to test and filter the input.
- a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) expression to create the decimal value as `parseInt` will return `NaN` for empty strings. The ternary checks if the string is empty evaluating to `""` or if there is a number the ternary evaluates to the decimal value.
- [HTMLInputElement.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) (inherited from `HTMLElement`) to focus the input element when loaded.

I have modified the HTML and CSS to fit the snippet window a little better.

```js
"use strict";
const binaryInput = document.getElementById("binaryInput");
const decimalOutput = document.getElementById("decimalOutput");
const inputWarning = document.getElementById("inputWarning");
binaryInput.addEventListener('change', update);
binaryInput.addEventListener('keyup', update);
binaryInput.focus();

const WARNING_TIME = 2000; // in ms
var warningTimer;
function hidWarning() {
   inputWarning.classList.add("hideWarning");
}
function showWarning() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    warningTimer = setTimeout(hidWarning, WARNING_TIME);
    inputWarning.classList.remove("hideWarning");
}
function update() {
    var value = binaryInput.value;
    if (/[^01]/g.test(value)){
        binaryInput.value = value = value.replace(/[^01]/g, "");
        showWarning();
    }
    decimalOutput.textContent = value === "" ? "" : parseInt(value, 2);
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #2e2e2e;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Heebo, sans-serif;
}
.form-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}
input {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 0.125rem solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;    
}

.inputWarning { color: #F88 }
.hideWarning { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="form-body">
  <h2>Binary to Decimal Calculator</h2>
  <label for="binaryInput">Enter a binary value<span id="inputWarning" class="inputWarning hideWarning"> [Only valid digits 0 and 1 permitted]</span></label>
  <input id="binaryInput" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8">
  <h3>Decimal Value: <span id="decimalOutput"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the type of in-depth feedback I was hoping for. It's a much smoother operation. I think the only area I am not too familiar with is the RegExp but this will come with time

Comment: When you give an element an id, it already exists as a property on the window object. You don't need to use getElementById. Since you are using the same name you can just remove those 3 lines entirely. By the way, your opening and closing tag doesn't match for the headings.

Comment: @Kruga If I don't add a detailed explanation regarding direct referencing I get down-voted for using them eg https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184295/120556 I volunteer answers and time is not always available to provide a defense of direct referencing as in the following https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/217497/120556